# Como visualizar e fazer manutenções em um banco de dados SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Olá,

Comecei recentemente a estudar o banco SQLite e gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de visualizar minhas tabelas e a própria estrutura do banco por completo, igual ao pgAdmin e o MySQL Workbench. Se pelo menos por USB eu consiga acessar e modificar esses bancos do meu celular.

Answer (score 1):

existe o SQLiteStudio, com ele você consegue ver suas tabelas.
[Site oficial do programa!](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/index.rvt?act=download)

Comment: E você poderia me ensinar como pegar o banco que ja estou utilizando no meu celular?